# How are values compared in NatTable with GlazedLists?

Tags: nattable, glazedlists

I do use NatTables with GlazedLists. I can not find in documentation, how default comparator compares values. According ASCII code values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have not configured any other `Comparator` for a column, NatTable will use its [`DefaultComparator`](https://github.com/eclipse/nebula.widgets.nattable/blob/master/org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.core/src/org/eclipse/nebula/widgets/nattable/config/DefaultComparator.java). The `DefaultComparator` checks if both objects are of type `Comparable`, if so it will use the `compareTo(String)` method of that type. If not it will try to get the String representation of the object and perform a comparison based on that. String itself is also a `Comparable` so you find the detailed information how Strings are compared in the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Thank you @Dirk, "The comparison is based on the Unicode value of each character in the strings"